# Проверяйте пожалуйста предложении. Вы знаете имя и фамилию первый женщина-космонавт

Tags: морфология

Проверяйте пожалуйста предложении. Вы знаете имя и фамилию первый женщина-космонавт

Answer (score 2):

Правильно так:

Проверьте, пожалуйста, предложение!

*Вы знаете имя и фамилию первой женщины-космонавта?*